# Rules for Invertibility When Multiplying Matricies

Tags: linear-algebra

If I have a $6\times6$ matrix $Z$ that can be written as $Z=DH$, where $D$ is a $6\times5$ matrix and H is a $5\times6$ matrix, tell me what theorem, definition, reason why $Z$ is not invertible.

I know that $H$ is not invertible as $\text{rank}(H)\ne5$. How does $H$'s not invertible nature make $Z$ not invertible?

Comment: $H$ must necessarily take some non-zero vector to zero.

Comment: If $H$ does not take some non-zero vector to zero, can't the dot product of D and H yield a matrix that defines a linear transformation that takes a non-zero vector to zero thus making Z invertible?

Comment: There indeed exists a $6x6$ matrix that is invertible. So can't $Z$ be the invertible $6x6$ matrix?

Answer (score 1):

Simply invoke Sylvester's inequality:
$$ \operatorname{rank}(DH) \leq \min(\operatorname{rank}(D),\operatorname{rank}(H)) \leq 5
$$

Comment: Does there exist a similar inequality for kernels rather than ranks?

Comment: @katie Try Rank-Nullity Theorem.